# Oracle SQL displaying data from multiple records

Tags: sql, oracle

Sorry if I am not explaining this properly, I am relatively new to SQL.

In oracle have a table describing properties (city, property type, cost of rent per month, other information)

My question is: assuming 3 unique property types (hotel, house, empty lot), how can I show which cities do not have all 3 types of properties?

Comment: Show sample data, the expected result and what you have tried.

Comment: Either `GROUP BY` or `Analytic COUNT() OVER()`, see my answer for examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways,

1. `GROUP BY`
2. Analytic `COUNT() OVER()`

For example, Let's say I have sample data of 3 cities, where city 1 has all the property types satisfied, rest other cities are not having all the required property types.

**Using GROUP BY**

```
SQL> -- sample table data
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 1 city, 'hotel' property FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 1 city, 'house' property FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 1 city, 'empty' property FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 2 city, 'hotel' property FROM dual UNION ALL
  6  SELECT 2 city, 'house' property FROM dual UNION ALL
  7  SELECT 2 city, 'scrap' property FROM dual UNION ALL
  8  SELECT 3 city, 'empty' property FROM dual UNION ALL
  9  select 3 city, 'house' property from dual
 10  )
 11  -- query
 12  SELECT city
 13     FROM data
 14   WHERE property IN ('hotel', 'house', 'empty')
 15  GROUP BY city
 16  HAVING COUNT(property) < 3
 17  /

      CITY
----------
         2
         3

SQL>
```

**Using Analytic COUNT() OVER()**

```
SQL> -- sample table data
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 1 city, 'hotel' property FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 1 city, 'house' property FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 1 city, 'empty' property FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 2 city, 'hotel' property FROM dual UNION ALL
  6  SELECT 2 city, 'house' property FROM dual UNION ALL
  7  SELECT 2 city, 'scrap' property FROM dual UNION ALL
  8  SELECT 3 city, 'empty' property FROM dual UNION ALL
  9  select 3 city, 'house' property from dual
 10  )
 11  -- query
 12  SELECT DISTINCT city
 13  FROM
 14    (SELECT t.* ,
 15      COUNT(property) OVER(PARTITION BY city ORDER BY city) rn
 16    FROM DATA t
 17    WHERE property IN ('hotel', 'house', 'empty')
 18    )
 19  WHERE rn < 3
 20  /

      CITY
----------
         2
         3

SQL>
```

Comment: thank you, this is what ended up working for me. I added distinct into `count(property)` in the first solution

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Yes, I missed DISTINCT in first query. You could use either of the queries. Please mark it as answered, it will help others.

Answer (score 1):

`GROUP BY` solution, make sure there are less than 3 different property types for each city returned:

```
select city
from tablename
where property_type in ('hotel', 'house', 'empty lot')
group by city
having count(distinct property_type) < 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL query should be

SELECT City
FROM YourTable
WHERE hotel <> 'hotelname' and house <> 'housename' and emptylot <> 'name'

assuming
Hotel, House, Emptylot is column name in your database.

Answer (score 0):

(**Edited**)Try this query :

```
  select t.city  from table_name t 
  where t.city NOT IN 
  (select city from table_name 
   where ( property_type ='hotel' or 
           property_type ='house' or 
           property_type ='Empty lot')
  );
```

(Query returning cities where all three types of property are not present):

```
 select t.city from table t inner join 
  (select city from table 
   where property_type not in ('House','Hotel','Empty lot')) x 
 on t.city=x.city 
 group by t.city 
 having count(*)<3 ;
```

Comment: when I try this it excludes all of the data because all cities have at least one of the property types, but not necessarily all 3

Comment: Still seems to exclude all data. When I use: 
`SELECT city, property_type, count(property_type)
from table
group by city, property_type
order by city` I get a list of the cities based on how many of each type of properties they have. Is there a way to only show cities that have less than 3 rows returned, or can I only aggregate it once?

Comment: @eagles2016, Use this query  : `select t.city from table t inner join (select city from table where property_type not in ('House','Hotel','Empty lot')) x
on t.city=x.city group by t.city having count(*)<3 ;`

Answer (score 0):

Could be something like this:

```
SELECT City
FROM YourTable
WHERE [property type] != 'hotel' OR
      [property type] != 'empty lot' OR
      [property type] != 'house'
```